# Retrieve a pdf's bookmark data using VanillaJS/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, directory

I'm trying to retrieve a pdf's meta data, looking specifically for a bookmark's page number using VanillaJS/node.js with no libraries. The file is located locally on the desktop.

I found this bit of code in another answer but it only returns the length of the document. I have tried to change the regex to look for letters, but if then returns an array of 500000 letters.

Is it even possible? If libraries are required, does anyone know of one that can do this?

Thanks

```
const fs = require('fs').promises

let rawData = await fs.readFile(fullPath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error('test error', err);
              return;
            }
        });


async function pdfDetails(data) {
          return new Promise(done => {
              let Pages2 = data.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g);
              let regex = /<xmp.*?:(.*?)>(.*?)</g;
              let meta = [{
                Pages
              }];
              let matches = regex.exec(data);
              while (matches != null) {
                matches.shift();
                meta.push({
                  [matches.shift()]: matches.shift()
                });
                matches = regex.exec(data);
              }
              done(meta);
          });
        }

let details = await pdfDetails(rawData)

console.log(details)
```

Comment: I think all I'd need is the page of the bookmark's location and the name of the bookmark.

Comment: Thanks KJ, I think I've concluded that it's not very feasible to use VanillaJS without libraries or other third party software to parse pdf data

Comment: The LEADTOOLS JavaScript Document Library has the [lt.Document.DocumentStructure](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/javascript/dox/documentstructure.html) class which manages the internal links of a document after it is loaded. This can call the [Parse](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/javascript/dox/documentstructure-parse.html) method which parses both bookmarks and internal page links in a given document. If this library interests you, you can download a free evaluation from the website [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads) (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)

Answer (score 1):

Due to the difficulty of using vanilla JS, and problems with libraries that may have worked (due to node version conflicts), I ended up using PDFTron services.